# Do someone know how to print in good way the models from H2o in Jupyter-Notebooks?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, h2o

I am newbie using the H2o framework for machine learning. I trying it from python, (jupyter notebooks). When I print the output of the model in the notebook the columns overlap to each other.

Do someone know how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To print the summary, try `mDL.summary().as_data_frame()`. In general, `as_data_frame()` will fix the formatting of most tables in h2o3.